# "npm start" in bash script is not working remotely

Tags: bash, npm, console, debian, npm-start

I have a bash script that include "npm start" , and i run this bash from a telegram API remotely, normally does not work. but if i just login to the root user in console of my debian-stretch , that API does work ! 
 so where is my problem ? 
thanks

this code is in bash :

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -dm sudo npm start --prefix /root/gbot/
```

Comment: this error i get  =   sudo: npm: command not found

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use Telegram API before. However I think you are facing the problem of root permission.

Running from a remote API may not use a `root` user (which seems can lead to a vulnerability problem). Then if you execute a command that needs `sudo`, it will ask you to input the root password to temporary gain a root privilege. However, if you are using a remote API, you may not have a way to input this root password, which leds you not able to get a root privilege, then you have no permission to run anything related to `sudo`.

To solve this, you may use command `expect` to automatically send the root password to the process of asking the password. However this may leads to a vulnerability.

A better solution may be changing the privilege (`chmod`) of this npm repo, or move it to some place where is more safety and don't need a too high privilege (may use `chmod` too).

Comment: I really appreciate your help in resolving the problem.  i have many bash like this with "sudo" that work remotely , but this is my first "npm" , i think the problem is in npm reference, or installation address. that do not recognize the npm.

Comment: @NimaZandKarimi Could you try to output the error stream to see why it is "does not work"?

Comment: i use this method and don't get any things :   screen -dm sudo npm start --prefix /root/gbot/ 2> bot6.log 1> bot7.log 3> bot8.log